# Please Help me with this summation, I can't understand how to start?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find $N$, for

$$\displaystyle N = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {n} \times 10^{\displaystyle  \ \ -(n+1)(\lfloor \log n \rfloor + 1) + \sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor \log n \rfloor} 10^r \  \ }  $$.

I don't know how to start, I thought of first few terms, but it isn't helpful. Give me a hint or technique to do such kind of problems.

Also feel free to edit tags and question (if needed). I have no idea how to do this thus I am not able to share my attempt. But I really want to do this question. Give me any source file to get familiar with such question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Before I get sucked into this question: is the base of your logarithm $e$, $10$, or something else?

Comment: Why are you interested in this question?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: List out the first 21 terms, especially the power. Do you see a sequence in them?

Comment: @CalvinLin Are you assuming that the base of the logarithm is $10$?  I'm not seeing the pattern I expected.  When $n=10$ I get the exponent is $-33$  Is that right?

Comment: Yes and No. That's how I would start looking at the problem. FWIW I don't think it will simplify nicely.

Comment: @CalvinLin I would definitely try that.

Comment: @Integrand Base 10

Comment: @sampleuser Summations Like this drive me crazy, and I generate an urge to do it. (I do not keep record of time, thus sometimes it takes me months to solve them cause I do not look for answer until I find it). This is what gives me happiness, brother.

Comment: @saulspatz One of my friends gave me this.

Comment: It looks to me like there may be a typo in the formula.  I was expecting it to turn out to be the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) $C_{10}$ but it doesn't appear to be.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I have rectified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the logarithm here is base $10$, and I suspect that there is an error in the exponent on $10$ in the general term: I suspect that the sum should be

$$N=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot 10^{-(n+1)\left(\lfloor\log n\rfloor+1\right)+\sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}10^r},$$

for a reason that will become apparent when I evaluate the revised sum.

To do this, divide the sum into blocks according to the number of digits in $n$, i.e., according to $\lfloor\log n\rfloor$, since $\lfloor\log n\rfloor+1$ is the number of digits in the usual decimal representation of $n$.

For $1\le n\le 9$ we have

$$N_1=\sum_{n=1}^9n\cdot 10^{-(n+1)+1}=\sum_{n=1}^9n\cdot 10^{-n}=0.123456789;$$

note that this has $9$ decimal places.

For $10\le n\le 99$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
N_2&=\sum_{n=10}^{99}n\cdot 10^{-2(n+1)+11}\\
&=\sum_{n=10}^{99}n\cdot 10^{-2n+9}\\
&=10\cdot 10^{-11}+11\cdot 10^{-13}+\ldots+99\cdot 10^{-189}\\
&=0.0000000001011121314\ldots9899,
\end{align*}$$

which has $9+90\cdot 2=189$ decimal places. Note that

$$N_1+N_2=0.1234567891011121314\ldots9899.$$

For $100\le n\le 999$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
N_3&=\sum_{n=100}^{999}n\cdot 10^{-3(n+1)+111}\\
&=\sum_{n=100}^{999}n\cdot 10^{-3n+108}\\
&=100\cdot 10^{-192}+101\cdot 10^{-195}+\ldots+999\cdot 10^{-2889}\\
&=0.\underbrace{0\ldots0}_{189}100101102103104\ldots998999,
\end{align*}$$

which has $189+900\cdot3=2889$ decimal places. Moreover,

$$N_1+N_2+N_3=0.1234567891011121314\ldots9899100101102103104\ldots998999.$$

I leave it to you to verify that with the revised summation that I’ve used, the decimal expansion of $N$ is obtained by concatenating the positive integers in ascending order.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed , your suspected sum is true. :)

Comment: Yes, I thought of this method but I didn't knew that $\lfloor \log n \rfloor + 1 $ is the number of digits in the decimal expansion of $n$. But I considered same blocks.

Comment: I like your solution.

Comment: Do you have more questions in your knowledge (similar to this) ? If yes, Please send me some sources, or the question.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi: I’m afraid that I don’t; I just noticed that $\lfloor\log n\rfloor$ was constant over blocks of consecutive values of $n$ and decided to see whether those blocks had ‘nice’ sums.

Comment: No issues, brother.